# How to simulate a click in a SceneView?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am working on a viewshed viewer application that uses [ArcGIS' Viewshed Analysis example](https://codepen.io/pen?&editors=100) as a base. I have a calculator widget that takes coordinates and zooms to the specified location on the map when a submit button is pressed. The viewshed should then be calculated at that location. The SceneView has an event listener:

```
view.on("click", computeViewshed);
```

How do I simulate an "artificial" click using ArcGIS' API?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of simulating an artificial click, extract the code that does the analysis to a separate function that takes in a Point (latitude/longitude) as a parameter. Then call that function on SceneView click *and* when the submit button is pressed.